# getReserves() function does not provide the information of the swap price

Tags: price, sushiswap

I've made a function to get swap prices of the Sushiswap rates using getReserves() function. As I have learned, in order to get the current swap price of 2 tokens, I need to  divide the amount of reserves of the first token by the amount of reserves. But when I try to use this function I get the `call revert exception (method="getReserves()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.4.0)` error.

But the strange thing is that when I do the same function on wETH token, I get all the results I need - the actual price.

```
    const runBot = async () => {
    const sushiFactory = new ethers.Contract(
      '0xC0AEe478e3658e2610c5F7A4A2E1777cE9e4f2Ac',
      UniswapV2Factory.abi, wallet,
    );
    const uniswapFactory = new ethers.Contract(
      '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f',
      UniswapV2Factory.abi, wallet,
    );
    const usdcAddress = '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f';
    const wethAddress = '0x6b3595068778dd592e39a122f4f5a5cf09c90fe2';
  
    const sushi_address = '0x6b3595068778dd592e39a122f4f5a5cf09c90fe2'
    const bnb_address = '0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52'
    const usdc_address  = '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48'
    const eth_address = '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2'
    const dai_address = '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f'
    const btc_address = '0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599'

    let sushiEthDai;
    let uniswapEthDai;
  
    const loadPairs = async () => {
      sushiEthDai = new ethers.Contract(
        await sushiFactory.getPair(btc_address, dai_address),
        UniswapV2Pair.abi, wallet,
      );
      uniswapEthDai = new ethers.Contract(
        await uniswapFactory.getPair(btc_address, dai_address),
        UniswapV2Pair.abi, wallet,
      );
    };
  
    await loadPairs();

    provider.on('block', async (blockNumber) => {
      try {
        console.log(blockNumber);


    const sushiReserves = await sushiEthDai.getReserves();
    const uniswapReserves = await uniswapEthDai.getReserves();
    
    const reserve0Sushi = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(sushiReserves[0], 18));
    const reserve1Sushi = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(sushiReserves[1], 18));

    const reserve0Uni = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(uniswapReserves[0], 18));
    const reserve1Uni = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(uniswapReserves[1], 18));

    const priceUniswap = reserve0Uni / reserve1Uni;
    const priceSushiswap = reserve0Sushi / reserve1Sushi;
    
    const shouldStartEth = priceUniswap < priceSushiswap;
    const spread = Math.abs((priceSushiswap / priceUniswap - 1) * 100);
    
    console.log(`SUSHI PRICE ${reserve0Sushi / reserve1Sushi}`)
  }
    catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
     }
     })
     }
    
   runBot()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566262/exception-in-fetchpairdata-call-revert-exception-in-method-getreserves

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the tokens first, otherwise you will get 2 different pair addresses for each pair.

```
function sortTokens(address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address token0, address token1) {
require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2Library: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
(token0, token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS');
}
```